# NIC capable of receiving Corrupt frames

Tags: networking, network-adapter

I am working on a project which requires me to capture packets that don't pass the CRC 32 check. I did some digging and came across ethtool utility, using which we can change ethernet device parameters.

To allow the capture of packets, which do not pass the CRC 32 I need to use the following command:

ethtool -K *DEVname* -fcs on

ethtool -K *DEVname* -rx all on

However, for most NICs this option is fixed.

I need help finding cards that are capable of changing the -rx all option. Also, How can we check if a particular card has the option non-fixed, before purchasing it as I was unable to find documentation that explicitly specifies this.

Thanks in advance.